# Multiple definition of constant

Tags: c++

I have a constant defined in one of the files 1.h :

```
namespace x {
    const int var = 0xff;
}
```

This file is bundled as a part of a library say 1.a.

Now I include this 1.h in say 2.cpp

```
#include "1.h"
void func() {
    struct t;
    t.param_1 = x::var;
}
```

When i build this in to executable i get the following multiple definition error for the declared constant :

"./../../../include/c++/4.1.2/exception:57: multiple definition of x::var"

Comment: What system and compiler?

Comment: Is there include guard in `1.h`?

Comment: `struct t;` Please post your actual code.

Comment: @StoryTeller Using gcc 4.1.2 on rhel

Comment: Yes, include guard is there, and sry cannot post actual code

Comment: Yes, indeed you do. Probably because there are multiple definitions.

Comment: I have searched my whole code.. there is only one definition in that namespace as specified above.

Comment: Sounds like you const has external linkage, but that should only happen if you explicitly use the `extern` keyword. Is it so?

Comment: If you cannot post actual code, then create a dummy example which reproduces the problem, and post that.

Comment: oh what horrible abomination is the name `1.h` ... :)

Comment: perhaps you are including "1.h" more than once?

Comment: You will need to provide the smallest compilable example the reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Kevin That shouldn't matter if the include guard is there, and the OP says it's there in the comments.

Comment: Did you find the root cause ?